# How to Reduce Disk Space for SQL Server Database

Tags: sql-server

I have a database that uses much more disk space than is actually needed. It has reserved 171 GB but the data is only 1.9 GB. (the database was created a long time ago by someone else). SQL Server Version: 12.0.5659.1 (which I guess is SQL Server 2014)

[image: Disk Usage Report Before Shrink]

I want to get it down to a reasonable size like 2 or 3 GB.

I ran DBCC SHRINKFILE (N'XXXHelper_data', 4000, TRUNCATEONLY) but it only got rid of about 70 GB. Disk Usage Report After Shrink

[image: Disk Usage Report After Shrink]

I read somewhere that a DB cannot be shrunk to smaller than the size that was originally declared when the DB was created. (but don't know if that's true)

I have done some research and found that there may be several possible techniques to accomplish this (some of which could fragment indexes, etc.). I need some help picking the best one.

TIA

Comment: Shrinking files in your database is going to cause massive amount of fragmentation no matter what technique you use. As long as shrinking is not a frequent thing but is just a one off process then defragmenting the indexes is not big deal.

Comment: @SeanLange There's no need to defragment the indexes anyway, it doesn't make a difference performance-wise. But agreed, shrinking should only be done to fix *one-time* type of events.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why the file didn't shrink further was that you told SQL Server to *not* move pages from end of the data file to beginning of the file. This is what the TRUNCATEONLY option means. Then end-most page limits how small the file can be made.

Moving pages is expensive. It is logged to the transaction log etc etc. There are several reason why we discourage from doing shrink, in general. See [this](https://karaszi.com/why-you-want-to-be-restrictive-with-shrink-of-database-files), for example.

However, fragmentation, in particular, is not something that you will likely suffer from. See [this](https://sqlblog.karaszi.com/index-fragmentation-revisited/) for example.

In your particular situation, having so much free space in the file, you might find it OK to pay the price for getting the database file(s) smaller by doing a shrink. Only you can decide, weighting in the disadvantages of doing the shrink compared to the gain of having a smaller database file(s).